# Citation call-outs with natbib and authordate3

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am using the natbib package with the authordate3 bibliography style. I get this in the text: (First author *et al.* , date) and I would like to have this: (First author et al date), or even: (First author *et al* date), or: (First author *et al*, date). I tried to modify the bst file but wihtout any success.

Any help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I don't think the `authordate1-4` bibliography styles are designed to be used with `natbib`. They seem to require the `authordate1-4` package. Is using `biblatex` a possibility?

Comment: @AlanMunn -- Not sure about the other bib styles of the `authordate` package, but the `authoryear3` bib style seems to work just fine when used together with `natbib`.

Comment: @Mico It wasn't clear, and since it has its own package code, it seemed likely that there were potential incompatibilities.

Comment: @AlanMunn - The topic of compatibility piqued my interest. I found the following sentence in the abstract of the user guide of the `natbib` package: "[`natbib`] is compatible with the standard bibliographic style files, such as `plain.bst`, as well as with those for `harvard`, `apalike`, `chicago`, `astron`, `authordate`, ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `authordate3.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `authordate3-mod.bst`. (Do not modify an original, unrenamed file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `authordate3-mod.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Inside the file `authordate3-mod.bst`, locate all three instances of the string `{\em et~al.}`. (In my copy of the file, they occur on lines 268, 1038, and 1042.)

  Change all three instances of this string to `et~al`. Basically, you're removing `\em` and the trailing "period" (aka "full stop").
- Save the file `authordate3-mod.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. If you don't understand the preceding sentence, you should probably choose the first option...
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{authordate3}` to `\bibliographystyle{authordate3-mod}`.
- In the preamble, after loading the `natbib` package, issue the directive `\setcitestyle{aysep={}}`. This serves to eliminate the comma between author(s) and year in citation call-outs generated by `\citep`.
- Run a complete recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more) to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

A full MWE (mininal working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
\bibliographystyle{authordate3-mod}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
   @misc{abc:3001,author="A and B and C",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{abc:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine with me.